# in jsgantt-improved, all cols in left data table is not visible to users

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, gantt-chart

I am using jsgantt-improved in plotly dash to display the gantt-chart with data table.

this is my [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z530z.png)

left data table is not displaying all the columns.

this is my

```
json=[
{
"pID": 1,
"pName": "WBS1-Level-1",
"pStart": "2022-01-01",
"pEnd": "2022-01-05",
"pPlanStart": "",
"pPlanEnd": "",
"pClass": "ggroupblack",
"pLink": "",
"pMile": 0,
"pRes": "Mario",
"pComp": 0,
"pGroup": 1,
"pParent": 0,
"pOpen": 1,
"pDepend": "",
"pCaption": "",
"pNotes": "Some Notes text",
"category": "Planning",
"sector": "CMO"
},
{
"pID": 11,
"pName": "Activity 1",
"pStart": "2022-01-01",
"pEnd": "2022-11-01",
"pClass": "gmilestone",
"pLink": "",
"pMile": 1,
"pRes": "Henrique",
"pComp": 100,
"pGroup": 0,
"pParent": 1,
"pOpen": 1,
"pDepend": "",
"pCaption": "",
"pNotes": "",
"category": "Executive",
"sector": "CEO"
},
]

i have tried enable by passing these as params in setOptions()
vShowRes = 1;
vShowCost = 1;
vShowAddEntries = 1;
vShowComp = 1;
vShowStartDate = 1;
```

to display these cols in left data table.
but this columns are not visible to the users.

also tried to enable ShowStartDate using set function.

```
g.setShowStartDate(1);
```

can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.

I want the data table similar to [this](https://jsganttimproved.github.io/jsgantt-improved/docs/demo.html)

for more info on jsgantt-improved check [this out](https://github.com/jsGanttImproved/jsgantt-improved/blob/master/Documentation.md)